# How can I get the stdout history of a detached Docker container?

Tags: logs, docker

I would like to view the output history of a Docker container.  I am running the container like so:

```
docker run -itd --name mytest ubuntu:latest /bin/bash
```

I can then run the following commands:

```
docker exec -it mytest /bin/bash
root@f1b3fc8464d2:/# echo "it works"
it works
root@f1b3fc8464d2:/# exit
```

I then want to run some command to show me "it works" and the history of any other output, as I would have seen had I just initially stayed attached to the container the whole time.  Changing the initially run command or other kinds of enabling logging are acceptable.

Based on another StackExchange question, I've already tried this:

```
docker logs -f mytest
```

But it has no effect.  It doesn't show output history, and it doesn't show output that happens while the command is running.  It doesn't show anything.

I'm looking to log the standard output stream in general, rather than just stuff resulting from `docker exec`. The above logs command doesn't show any output, even though I know there have been some. I want my pseudo terminal created with the `-t` flag in the run command to be perpetual outputted to a file for later perusal.

Comment: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8662

Comment: What in particular are you trying to draw my attention to?

Comment: That `docker exec` doesn't log anything anywhere and that issue is a FR to add logging to `docker exec`

Comment: I'm looking to log stdout in general though, rather than just stuff as a result of docker exec.  The above logs command doesn't show any output of any kind at all, even though I know there has been some.  I essentially just want my pseudo terminal created with the -t flag in the run command to be perpetual outputted to a file for later perusal.

Comment: That's the point of the issue there - if there were something general, people would be using that for `docker exec` instead of filing FRs

Comment: Are you trying to log something more specifically? have you tried `echo`ing that?