# echo process started in ENTRYPOINT/CMD to host stdout while keeping container alive and detached?

Tags: docker

Using docker I am trying to print the login token for a jupyter notebook to stout on my host without attaching to the container. The container is just for running a notebook in a browser on the host.

With (attached) interactive mode and pseudo terminal `docker run -it`, I can start jupyter in the background and print the token. The Dockerfile `CMD` runs jupyter with `screen -S session_name -dm jupyter notebook...`, or alternatively `& disown`, and then does a bash loop `echo`ing the token when it is returned by `jupyter server list`. However, because this is the last item in `Dockerfile` `CMD` it terminates the container.

To be able to continue the container I have played with ending with running e.g. `bash`. This let's the container continue but because of `-it` the host shell is also attached to it.

Therefore, I added detached `-d` mode i.e. `docker run -itd`. But then I don't see the token on host stout anymore. For that I need to go run [`docker logs container-name-here`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/563382/how-can-i-get-the-stdout-history-of-a-detached-docker-container) which is common practice. Perhaps this is the easiest solution as I see it. *But I would like to avoid it if possible!*

I have tried removing `-it` with two alternative additions.

First, trying to attach to the disowned process adding the `docker run` flags `--privileged --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE` and adding to the dockerfile the below terminates the container as shown

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope`
gdb -p PID

...
Quit anyway? (y or n) [answered Y; input not from terminal]
Detaching from program: /usr/local/bin/python3.12, process 8
[Inferior 1 (process 8) detached]
```

Second, by adding to the dockerfile `script /dev/null` just before `screen`. The token was printed succesfully, but the container terminated (being the last CMD). Adding `script /dev/null; screen -r session_name` at the end returned

```
Script started, output log file is '/dev/null'.
# 
Script done.
Must be connected to a terminal.
```

Any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: So your container entry process writes something to `stdout`, and you want to be able to read that?  Have you tried `docker run -d ...` and then do a `docker container logs <containerid>`?

Comment: Thanks for commenting Andy. As stated, `-itd` and then `logs` does provide the information. I'd like to retrieve the info immediately from building and running the container, without the additional `logs` command afterwards if possible.

Comment: @Johan My best bet is that a hacky way to tackle this would be scripting it. Run the container, run a loop to check container's state (polling with either/both of `docker exec` and `docker logs`). Then break the while loop and grep it from the logs (again, could use exec if applicable).

Edit: there might be another way: use `ctrl-p` then `ctrl-q` to detach container once your eyes laid on whatever outcome you wanted. Docs: https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/container/attach/

You could do it with a separate `exec -it` or directly after `docker run -it`.

Comment: @cbugk cheers! The only working solution I could get was indeed by using logs after running the container. Not exactly what I asked for, but anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, this is not exactly the solution I asked for but the one I went with given the lack of a better alternative:

```
#!/bin/bash

# docker build+run -d or compose up -d ...

dock_jcontainer="$(docker container ls | awk '{if(NR>1) print $NF}' | grep py)" # I looked for a python container

while true; do
    if docker logs $dock_jcontainer 2>&1 | grep -q "To access the server"; then # Jupyter Notebook log outputs this string
        dock_jlogs=$(docker logs $dock_jcontainer 2>&1)
        break
    fi
done

...
```

You may want to not repeat `docker logs $dock_jcontainer 2>&1` by turning it into $() or {}.

Comment: I don't get dock_logs. Shouldn't you put it in the while loop? Also, surely you want `dock_jlogs="${dock_logs}"` Mr. @Johan. How would you run `dock_logs`, as it is not a function?

Comment: Hi @cbugk, yes, actually right now I am experimenting/struggling with the dock_logs. so far cannot get it to work. substituting it works fine though. will update this when I am done.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Container name
dock_jcontainer="$(docker container ls | awk '{if(NR>1) print $NF}' | grep py)"

# Blocking wait until log's grep result is not empty, runs every 2 seconds.
while [ -z "$(docker logs "${dock_jcontainer}" 2>&1 | grep -q 'To access the server')" ]; do
    sleep 2;
done;

# Prints the line you are looking for
printf "$(docker logs "${dock_jcontainer}" 2>&1 | grep -q 'To access the server')\n"

# Functionalize it if you'd like
function grepLogs() {
    docker logs "${dock_jcontainer}" 2>&1 | grep -q 'To access the server'
}; export -f grepLogs
```

Comment: okay +1 for getting rid of the while true